# How to check user permissions in Sonar plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube5.1

I am writing a Sonar plugin and need to display certain elements in my widget (*html.erb*) according to user roles (i.e. admin).

What is the recommended way to check permissions of the current user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked if these are accessible in plugins but you can try using `is_admin?` or `has_role?(:admin)`

See below links for usage,

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/server/sonar-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/app/views/components/index.html.erb

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/server/sonar-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/app/views/issues/manage.html.erb

Comment: Note that Ruby will be gone in 5.2.

Comment: What do you mean by gone? All UI is using Ruby. Are you removing all support for it? Is there some official documentation about it?